# Registration Form not Redirecting

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've been making this registration form with HTML, PHP, MYSQL.

So the config is as below. When I fill in the form and submit the page just reloads. I can't figure out if I'm missing something with the PHP or HTML.

I don't know what's happening.

**Maybe you can spot the error...**

```html
<?php
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    include('includes/config.php');

    if( isset( 
        $_POST['submit'],
        $_POST['firstname'],
        $_POST['lastname'],
        $_POST['email'],
        $_POST['mobile'],
        $_POST['username'],
        $_POST['password'] 
    ) ){

        $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=md5($_POST['password']);

        $sql ='insert into `users` 
            ( `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `mobile`, `username`, `password`, `status` ) 
                values 
            ( :firstname, :lastname, :email, :mobile, :username, :password, 1)';

        $query=$dbh->prepare( $sql );

        if( $query ){
            $query->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam(':mobile', $mobile, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $res=$query->execute();

            if( $res ){
                $lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
                if($lastInsertId){
                    echo "<script>
                        alert('Registration Sucessfull!');
                        location.href='login.php';
                    </script>";         
                }else{
                    $error="Something went wrong. Please try again";
                }
            }   
        }else{
            exit('Error: Failed to prepare SQL statement');
        }
    }
}

?>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html class="loading no-js" lang="en" data-textdirection="ltr">
  <!-- BEGIN: Head-->

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimal-ui">
    <meta name="description" content="Vuexy admin is super flexible, powerful, clean &amp; modern responsive bootstrap 4 admin template with unlimited possibilities.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="admin template, Vuexy admin template, dashboard template, flat admin template, responsive admin template, web app">
    <meta name="author" content="PIXINVENT">
    <title>Register Page - Vuexy - Bootstrap HTML admin template</title>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="assets/images/ico/apple-icon-120.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/images/ico/favicon.ico">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,600" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- BEGIN: Vendor CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/vendors/css/vendors.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/vendors/css/ui/prism.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/vendors/css/file-uploaders/dropzone.min.css">
    <!-- END: Vendor CSS-->

    <!-- BEGIN: Theme CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap-extended.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/colors.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/components.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/themes/dark-layout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/themes/semi-dark-layout.css">

    <!-- BEGIN: Page CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/core/menu/menu-types/horizontal-menu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/core/colors/palette-gradient.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/pages/authentication.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/plugins/file-uploaders/dropzone.css">
    <!-- END: Page CSS-->

    <!-- BEGIN: Custom CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/assets/css/style.css">
    <!-- END: Custom CSS-->

  </head>
  <!-- END: Head-->

  <!-- BEGIN: Body-->

  <body class="horizontal-layout horizontal-menu 1-column  navbar-floating footer-static bg-full-screen-image  blank-page blank-page" data-open="hover" data-menu="horizontal-menu" data-col="1-column">
    <!-- BEGIN: Content-->
    <div class="app-content content">
      <div class="content-overlay"></div>
      <div class="header-navbar-shadow"></div>
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="content-header row">
        </div>
        <div class="content-body">
          <section class="row flexbox-container" id="dropzone-examples">
            <div class="col-xl-8 col-10 d-flex justify-content-center">
              <div class="card bg-authentication rounded-0 mb-0">
                <div class="row m-0">
                  <div class="col-lg-6 d-lg-block d-none text-center align-self-center pl-0 pr-3 py-0">
                    <img src="assets/images/pages/register.jpg" alt="branding logo">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-6 col-12 p-0">
                    <div class="card rounded-0 mb-0 p-2">
                      <div class="card-header pt-50 pb-1">
                        <div class="card-title">
                          <h4 class="mb-0">Create Account</h4>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <p class="px-2">Fill the below form to create a new account.</p>
                      <div class="card-content">
                        <div class="card-body pt-0">
                          <form method="post" action="register.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="regform" onSubmit="return validate();" autocomplete="off">

                            <div class="form-label-group">
                              <input name="firstname" type="text" id="inputFirstname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" value="" required autocomplete="off">
                              <label for="inputFirstname">First Name</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-label-group">
                              <input name="lastname" type="text" id="inputLastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" value="" required autocomplete="off">
                              <label for="inputLastname">Last Name</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-label-group">
                              <input name="email" type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" value="" required autocomplete="off">
                              <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-label-group">
                              <input name="mobile" type="tel" id="inputtel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" value="" required autocomplete="off">
                              <label for="inputtel">Phone Number</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-label-group">
                              <input name="username" type="text" id="inputUsername" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="" required autocomplete="off">
                              <label for="inputUsername">Username</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-label-group">
                              <input name="password" type="password" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}" onchange="form.confirm_password.pattern = RegExp.escape(this.value);" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" value="" required autocomplete="off"
                                data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Please use at least one number, one lowercase and one uppercase letter and it should be at least six characters that are letters, numbers or the underscore">
                              <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-label-group">
                              <input name="confirm_password" type="password" id="inputCPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" value="" required autocomplete="off">
                              <label for="inputCPassword">Confirm Password</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-label-group">
                              <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="text-left">
                                  <fieldset class="checkbox">
                                    <div class="vs-checkbox-con vs-checkbox-primary">
                                      <input type="checkbox" name="terms" required>
                                      <span class="vs-checkbox">
                 <span class="vs-checkbox--check">
                  <i class="vs-icon feather icon-check"></i>
                 </span>
                                      </span>
                                      <span class="">I accept terms and conditions</span>
                                    </div>
                                  </fieldset>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="login.php" class="btn btn-outline-primary float-left btn-inline mb-50">Login</a>
                            <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right btn-inline mb-50">Register</button>
                          </form>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END: Content-->



    <!-- BEGIN: Vendor JS-->
    <script src="assets/vendors/js/vendors.min.js"></script>
    <!-- BEGIN Vendor JS-->

    <!-- BEGIN: Page Vendor JS-->
    <script src="assets/vendors/js/ui/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
    <!-- END: Page Vendor JS-->

    <!-- BEGIN: Theme JS-->
    <script src="assets/js/core/app-menu.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/core/app.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/scripts/components.js"></script>
    <!-- END: Theme JS-->

    <!-- Loading Scripts -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fileinput.js"></script>
    <script src="js/chartData.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

  </body>
  <!-- END: Body-->

  </html>
```

I've been looking into this for a while and I can't seem to spot the error!

Comment: As you have an event handler bound to the form can you post that function?

Comment: Also - it looks like your SQL has a spurious `1` at the end of the values so your statement would fail

Comment: Sorry, I am a complete newbie, when it comes to PHP / MySQL

Comment: How do I add the event handler?

Comment: One other point: Do NOT use `md5` to hash the user's password, it simply is not safe enough as `md5` has been considered broken for several years now. Use `password_hash` instead and on the flip-side use `password_verify`

Comment: You edited the question but have not added the javascript function `validate` which is what either submits or does not  submit the form....Is the db being updated now but still redirecting to wrong location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ought to check that all the required fields are available in the POST array before proceeding and the SQL needed to be modified to remove the random number `1` at the end of the input values. When prepareing SQL statements you should use the return value from the `prepare` method to ensure that the statement was created successfully rather than blindly relying upon it - a similar approach when calling the `execute` method will further help fork the program logic.

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    include('includes/config.php');

    if( isset( 
        $_POST['submit'],
        $_POST['firstname'],
        $_POST['lastname'],
        $_POST['email'],
        $_POST['mobile'],
        $_POST['username'],
        $_POST['password'] 
    ) ){

        $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=md5($_POST['password']);

        $sql ='insert into `users` 
            ( `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `mobile`, `username`, `password` ) 
                values 
            ( :firstname, :lastname, :email, :mobile, :username, :password )';

        $query=$dbh->prepare( $sql );

        if( $query ){
            $query->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam(':mobile', $mobile, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $res=$query->execute();

            if( $res ){
                $lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
                if($lastInsertId){
                    echo "<script>
                        alert('Registration Sucessfull!');
                        location.href='profile.php';
                    </script>";         
                }else{
                    $error="Something went wrong. Please try again";
                }
            }   
        }else{
            exit('Error: Failed to prepare SQL statement');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One more question.. Why is the page redirecting to index.php INSTEAD OF profile.php?

Comment: Rather then using `javascript` to popup a message and then redirect you would be better simply using PHP for that and display a temporary message on`profile.php`. Why does it redirect to `index.php` - don't know for sure. Does it popup the alert message?

Comment: yes, after i click register it makes a popup message saying 'Registration Sucessfull!' and then takes me to index.php.

Answer (score 0):

i found the error on this line

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO users(firstname,lastname, email, mobile, username, password) 
VALUES(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :mobile, :username, :password, 1)";
```

why 1 at end??
i just reoved ,1 from end its worked

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO users(firstname,lastname, email, mobile, username, password) 
VALUES(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :mobile, :username, :password)";
```

Comment: i removed the one and updated the code above. Still just reloads the register page and no entries in database..

Comment: @CullenCarstens if you have php code in same page remove this action="register.php" from starting form tag

Comment: I corrected the code above, it was for the status;)